# PHP randomly errors undefined offset

Tags: php, ajax

I am having a problem with undefined offset errors. I have read many related posts and I know that it is because the array key is returning undefined. However, the structure of my code 'should' guarantee that the referenced array key's are defined.

I am filling an html select input using the following:

```
echo "<option>" . $row['year'] . "|" . $model . "|" . $row['date'] . "|" . $row['status'] . "</option>";
```

The year date and status columns of this select are all the same size, but the model is variable length, so I used:

```
$model = str_pad($row['model'],10,".",STR_PAD_BOTH);
$model = str_replace(".", "&nbsp;", $model);
```

The option output looks like: 2004| R32 Golf |06/05/2014|Open. The "." padding/replace retains the space between the two words in later code.

The 'onchange' event of this input calls a javascript/ajax to another php file passing the value of the option.
This file called by ajax does the following:

```
$Job=($_GET['job']);
$Job = htmlentities($Job);
$jobInfo = explode ( "|",  $Job );
```

The output from this looks like: 0->2004  1->&nbsp;R32 Golf/&nbsp;  2->06/05/2014  3->Open.
So lastly, I replace &nbsp; with empty strings again.

```
$model=str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $jobInfo[1]);
```

The keys are used to query MySQL and fill form fields.

So the problem, when I select from my list, sometimes (70%) it returns properly and fills the fields and sometimes (30%) it returns undefined offset 1, undefined offset 2 and undefined offset 3.
It appears to be completely random, but the delimiter '|' and implode should always return an array with keys 0,1,2 and 3.

This problem seems highly specific, but I am new here and wanted to provide as much information as possible in hopes of finding a solution. It has been difficult to reproduce this problem without the select list and ajax call.

JS ajax: (Sloppy)

```
function getJob(jobInfo)
{ 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
{
if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
     {
    results = xmlhttp.responseText.split("~");
        document.getElementById('address').value = results[0];
//more results[]

 } else {
   alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + xmlhttp.statusText);
}}}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getJob.php?job="+jobInfo,true);
    xmlhttp.send();   
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you doing all that work when you could just specify a value for the option signifying a unique ID?

Comment: Are you sure `$_GET['job']`'s value always contains the properly formatted string?  My guess is that `$Job` doesn't contain the values you think it does in some (70%) situations.  Try outputting the value of `$Job` and see if that's the case when it isn't working properly. Can you provide your JS that gets the select's value and does the Ajax request?

Comment: Because the list is populated from a MySQL query and is repopulated depending on the way the form is filled.

Comment: select passing it's value onchange.
Outputting $Job returns properly on success, returns nothing on error: undefined offset.
I would suspect that this is the problem, but unclear as to why it wouldn't pass properly.
Clicking the same select option 5 times: 2x <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 1 in <b> etc... and 3x properly return and fill form

Comment: Following what Devon suggested, I saved the MySQL query to a session variable and assigned my options an integer value to pass to my function so that I could just query from within my function and select the matching value using a fetch loop. My error now is a random undefined variable for my query->fetch. This suggests that $_GET is occasionally not receiving properly. Any ideas for why this is happening? Would $_POST (or another session var) be more reliable?